# How to test mongoid's embedded documents?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, mongoid

I have created a rails 4 app with mongoid as odm. I can test all models with mongoid-rspec gem successfully but I can not emebedded documents. I could not find a way to do that.

This is the basic model:

```
class Project::Type
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps
  include Mongoid::Paranoia

  store_in session: 'project', collection: 'type'

  embeds_many :rules, :class_name => "Project::TypeRule"

  field :name, type: String
  field :timing, type: String

  index({ name: 1 }, { unique: false, name: 'project_type_name', background: true })
end
```

This is the embedded document:

```
class Project::TypeRule
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps
  include Mongoid::Paranoia

  embedded_in :type ,:inverse_of => :rules

  TYPES = ["internal_link", "external_link","h1"]

  field :name,          type: String
  field :rule_type,     type: String
  field :value,         type: String
  field :count,         type: Integer
end
```

This is the test script:

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe Project::Type, :type => :model do
  let(:type) { create(:project_type) }

  it { should be_stored_in :type }

  # Associations
  it { should embed_many(:rules) }

  #Fields
  it { should have_fields(:name).of_type(String) }
  it { should have_fields(:timing).of_type(String) }
  it { should be_timestamped_document }
  it { should be_paranoid_document }

  #Indexes
  it { should have_index_for(name: 1).with_options(unique: false, name: 'project_type_name', background: true) }
end
```

I have searched on google about that but unfortunately there is no any clue.
What is the proper way of testing embedded documents?

Comment: What is exactly the problem ? The test don't work ?

Comment: I want to test embedded documents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are testing that Type has embed many rules. Now you should test the other side:

```
describe Project::TypeRule, :type => :model do
  # Associations
  it { should be_embedded_in(:type).as_inverse_of(:rules) }

  # Fields
  it { should have_fields(:name).of_type(String) }
  ...
end
```